# Mingw gives my a libwinpthread-1.dll was not found error when compiling code

Tags: c, dll, mingw

I just downloaded and installed Mingw. I also setup the system environment variables for `C:\MinGW\bin` and `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`.  I wanted to test to see if I had installed it correctly (it seemed to be since running `gcc --version` worked), so I wrote hellow world in c and tried to compile with `gcc main.c -o hello_world.exe`.  However I got the error:

"The code execution cannot proceed because libewinpthread-1.dll" was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

I have tired reinstalling it and restarting my computer.  I have also tried to see if this problem has occurred to others, and while there are a few places it is mentioned, I can't seem to find a solution mentioned.  I have thought about trying to download the dll separately, but if I remember correctly, downloading dlls is a big no no.

Awhile ago I installed mingw though chocolatey and it seemed to be working.  I have deleted that download from my computer and removed the paths, since I wanted to try to install it the normal way.  Could this be part of the error?

Any ideas what the issue could be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have built an .exe file that depends on libwinpthread-1.dll.

Solutions to make sure the .exe can run:

- Add the MinGW `bin` path to your PATH so `libwinpthread-1.dll` - this would only fix it for your own system so I wouldn't recommend this if you want to use the .exe file on other systems.
- Copy `libwinpthread-1.dll` from MinGW in the same folder as your .exe file. This is generally needed for any shared dependancy library your .exe is linked against.
- Build a static .exe (`--static` linker flag) to avoid the shared (.dll) dependancy.

Comment: In my case, the solution was "*Build a static .exe (`--static` linker flag) to avoid the shared (.dll) dependancy.*" - Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! probably is an error, cause MinGW is a bit stinky when it comes to DLLs
Here are some things you have to check:
Make sure the variable helding the location of MinGW is named "path"
and its pointing at: `C:\MinGW64\bin`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think my path is okay.  It is "C:\MinGW\bin".  Your path says MinGW64.  From what I understand that is a different version of Mingw correct?  maybe I will try installing that instead.

Comment: Yeah, i can send you a tutorial if you want

Comment: I think I got it! I will try it out! Thanks!

Comment: No problem :- )

Comment: Hey, I installed it and set the system variables and it still didn't work.  I tried restarting my computer and now it seems to be working!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool! Pleese tell me if you encouter another problem

Answer (score -1):

When you compile code, add this:

```
--static
```

as a parameter to the compilator, it should fix most of `dll` problems